# What is a good way to quickly develop a mock GUI?

Tags: gui, user-interface, graphic-design, wireframing

I'm looking for a method/tool/software to easily create a GUI. The GUI should look good, but nothing very fancy. It should have checkboxes, lists, radio buttons etc.

The important thing is that since this is just a mock, it should be quick to prepare. While I am a programmer and know C/Python, I would prefer something where I can just drag and drop elements and make a GUI rather than code.

The tool must be free or very cheap. I thought of Dreamweaver, but it's expensive and I guess I'd need a small learning curve (CSS, HTML).

What should I choose?

Comment: If you have Microsoft Office already installed, then Access would be a good way to create a GUI layout using drag and drop (buttons, checkboxes, and lists). You don't have to worry about programming a database since it's just a mock. I'm not sure LibreOffice Base can do it, but it's the free equivalent. If you're okay with a little coding, then also check out [QT Creator](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Category:Tools::QtCreator)

Comment: [Balsamiq](https://balsamiq.com/) is 79 USD, not sure if cheap enough for you but it's a great tool.

Comment: For which operating system(s)? Microsoft Windows? What about web applications (hosted, self-hosted)?

Comment: Windows 7, or any Linux works for me. Web applications are fine too.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [Pencil](http://pencil.evolus.vn/):

- free (+ open-source)
- Windows/Linux/Mac + can be used as a Firefox add-on too
- Can be used to create a scratch for application or website:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Okay, but have you used it? What are some unintuitive aspects of it? Drawbacks?

Comment: @ParthianShot I've briefly used it a while ago, I don't recall except than it did the job I was supposed to get done :/

Answer (score 3):

You can use [moqups](https://moqups.com/#!/):

- HTML 5 app
- Vectorial
- Unlimited team members for all the premium plans

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Answering my own question, the one I'm using is Axure. I was able to quickly start off with a mock application. It's free for a month, but it's expensive to buy after that.

This is a sample-

[image: sample Axure project]

Answer (score 1):

+1 on using Webflow. My workflow has gone

from:
Photoshop > [unknown developer stuff] > client

to:
Photoshop > lo-fi prototype (grayscale) > hi-fi prototype (theming) > client

I can now publish full wireframes based on client specs before even starting the project sometimes. Pretty intense.

Full disclosure: some bias since I work for Webflow but before joining the team I used Webflow daily for client projects - transformed my workflow entirely.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend creating a Windows Forms application using the free Visual Studio Community Edition. You have access to a wide range of User Interface controls and you can even add some basic programming actions (button on click) to show how the program would work.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend [Webflow](https://webflow.com/) for advanced prototyping:

- it has a free version (limited to two pages only)
- coding is done in a visual manner which allows non-programmers to create fully functional web pages
- it does require a learning curve and it is actually a highly modernized Dreamweaver, but let me assure you, the high-fidelity prototyping that you would achieve would pay off a number of times.