# GUI builder on concept level

Tags: gui, user-interface

I am looking for a software that allows me to build generic styled GUIs for concept purposes. It's purpose would be to give mainly non-programmers a tool to quickly scribble a few screens and visualize how they are connected.

Example: Let's say I want to visualize a feature for a mobile app that doesn't yet exist. I would use the GUI builder to

1. create a screen with a list of buttons (to navigate to further
   screens).
2. create a second screen that shows the situation when the
   first button is pressed.
3. create a third screen that shows the
   situation when the second button is pressed
4. connect the screens
   accordingly with lines or arrows

and so on.

It would be nice to have a toolbox with all the default elements available on real GUI builders like checkboxes, radio buttons, text fields.

Until now I would just use a pen and a piece of paper to scribble stuff like this but I wonder if there is any software that can assist on this topic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Wireframing

Terms used for such work include [`wireframe`](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Website_wireframe) and `mockups` and `prototyping`.

There many tools available for this now. Some are web-based, some are native apps. See [this list comparing wire-framing tools.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_software_prototyping_tools)

Some tools try to create realistic images simulating actual screen widgets. I prefer the tools that use cruder hand-drawn sketch-appearance images as that communicates to the reader that these are mere plans rather than finished software screen-shots.

## Balsamiq

[Balsamiq](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balsamiq) was one of the first and best such tools.

## OmniGraffle

Mac & iOS 
users might consider the general drawing tool [OmniGraffle](https://www.omnigroup.com/omnigraffle), and add a stencil for wireframing.

But this tool does not have all the slick features of a dedicated wire framing tool. On the upside, a businessperson might find learning this tool useful for other tasks such as org charts, flow charts, and diagramming.

You can find many such stencils at [Graffletopia](https://www.graffletopia.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I am using [pencil](https://pencil.evolus.vn/) as suggested here: [What is a good way to quickly develop a mock GUI?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/10485/what-is-a-good-way-to-quickly-develop-a-mock-gui) . it's not exactly what I was looking for but pretty close with neat shapes and stencils for web, android and ios gui elements and forms

Answer (score 0):

How about Netbeans plus JavaFX and the GUI SceneBuilder builder tool?  VERY reminiscent of the quick GUI development that VisualBasic 4/5 gave you (only thing I miss about VB in the 90s...)

That would even let you take the layout they've created, properly name the objects, and start writing code.

Here's how I'd set it up - create a VirtualBox VM running LinuxMint 18.x.

[Install Java 8 from the webupd8 repo](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html) - (Mint is based on Ubuntu, these instructions Just Work)- .

Install Netbeans IDE from a [direct download from the netbeans.org website](https://netbeans.org/downloads/), do it as the root user using `sudo`.  Download the "all" package.

Install the [JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0 `.deb` package](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafxscenebuilder-1x-archive-2199384.html#javafx-scenebuilder-2.0-oth-JPR) from the Oracle website. Link is hard to find it is http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafxscenebuilder-1x-archive-2199384.html#javafx-scenebuilder-2.0-oth-JPR

Start Netbeans, create a new project, select "JavaFX" and then "JavaFX FXML Application".  Once the project loads, in the left side file management pane, select the projects `.fxml` file, right click and select Open.  You'll get the GUI builder.  Drag and drop, knock yourself out.

Comment: thanks but I would prefer not using a real GUI builder integrated in some IDE because it should be a slim tool for non-programmers for rapid prototyping some screens visually (and maybe print the result or put in on slides) without any programming knowledge